# LINQ Query datatable Issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a DataTable that looks like this right now

```
California  2018    v32
Texas       2017    v31
New Jersey  2017    v31
Maine       2017    v31
New York    2014    v31
Alaska      2010    v29
```

I want the output to be like this using a LINQ Query

```
v32
     2018
     California

v31
     2017
     Texas
     New Jersey
     Maine

    2014
    New York

v29
    2010
    Alaska
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This Datatable will be attached to a asp.net repeater control

Comment: Any one?? please  help

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Faker
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }

        public Faker(string state, int year, string version)
        {
            State = state;
            Year = year;
            Version = version;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ls = new List<Faker>
        {
            new Faker("California", 2018, "v32"),
            new Faker("Texas", 2017, "v31"),
            new Faker("New Jersey", 2017, "v31"),
            new Faker("Maine", 2017, "v31"),
            new Faker("New York", 2014, "v31"),
            new Faker("Alaska", 2010, "v29"),
        };


        ls.GroupBy(x => x.Version)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => 
                {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Key);

                x.GroupBy(y => y.Year)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(y => {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{y.Key}");

                        y.GroupBy(z => z.State)
                            .ToList()
                            .ForEach(z => Console.WriteLine($"\t{z.Key}"));
                         Console.WriteLine();
                    });
                });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I doesn't give me the desired output the way I want

Comment: Any one Please help

Comment: What is it not doing?

Comment: It is displaying duplicate values